# Spring Cache: force update cache based on condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache, caffeine

I have a list of jobs that need to be cached (by id). In some cases however, it is important to have the latest version of a job, and the cache needs to be bypassed (force update). When that happens, the newly fetched job should be placed in the cache.

I implemented it like this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "jobs", key = "#id", condition = "!#forceRefresh", sync = true)
public Job getJob(String id, boolean forceRefresh) {
    // expensive fetch
}
```

Desired behavior:

- `getJob("123", false)` => job v1 is returned (fetched from the cache if present)
- `getJob("123", true)` => job v2 is returned (updated version, fetched from db)
- `getJob("123", false)` => job v2 is returned (**updated version, fetched from cache**)

In reality, the last call `getJob("123", false)` returns job **v1**, the stale version. It seems like the second call (forced update) does not update the value in the cache.

How can I achieve the correct behavior here?

Cache config (using Caffeine):

```
CaffeineCache jobs = new CaffeineCache("jobs", Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(100)
        .build());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case `forceRefresh` is true, Spring cache won't be activated because of the condition `condition = "!#forceRefresh"`. Hence, the cache value won't be updated.

You need to explicitly tell Spring to update the cache value with `@CachePut` in case `forceRefresh` is true:

```
@Caching(
    cacheable = {@Cacheable(cacheNames = "jobs", key = "#id", condition = "!#forceRefresh")},
    put = {@CachePut(cacheNames = "jobs", key = "#id", condition = "#forceRefresh")}
)
public Job getJob(String id, boolean forceRefresh) {
    // expensive fetch
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.17.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-put -- *Note that using CachePut and Cacheable annotations on the same method is generally strongly discouraged...*

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.17.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-put _"... with the exception of specific corner-cases (such as annotations having conditions that exclude them from each other)."_

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this problem before and solved it a couple of ways.  The easiest way to solve it is to all your updates to `Job` done through this same `JobService` you are using. If that is the case you just do this:

```java
    @Caching(evict = {
            @CacheEvict(value = "jobs", key = "#job.id") })
    public void updateJob( Job job ) {
```

This way when the `Job` is updated it will be evicted in the cache and your next call to `getJob` will pull a fresh one.

The next way is if you have some other process updating your database and `updateJob` is not used to update the actual source.  At that point, I have implemented it where I built a Quartz Job to refresh/update my cache entry on a schedule (i.e. every 15 mins). It looks something like this.

```java
    @Autowired
    CacheManager cacheManager;

    public void refreshJobs() {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache( "jobs" );

        for ( Job job : getJobs() ) {
            cache.put( job.getId(), job );
        }
    }
```

You might get some stale Jobs with that solution, but you know it is being refreshed every 5, 10 or 15 mins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, updates are done by some process I don't have control of, so the first solution is not an option for me. As for the second solution: I really need the latest version of the job when forceRefresh is true, so that won't work either.

Comment: How do you know when to call with forceRefresh of true?

Comment: That's a client decision. In my case, I get the parameter from the front end.